# A virtual file containing the concatenation of other files

Tags: filesystems, files, cat, fifo

Is there a way of creating a filesystem object akin to this:

```
mknod files p
cat file1 file2 ... fileN > files
```

but such that it can be seeked in, as if it were a regular file?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

On Linux-based operating systems, that can be done with network block devices or device mapper devices. The file you obtain is a block device.

With `nbd`:

```
ln -s /path/to/first-file file.0
...
ln -s /path/to/last-file file.19
nbd-server -C /dev/null -m 127.0.0.1:12345 file

sudo nbd-client localhost 12345 /dev/nbd0
```

(the concatenation is `/dev/nbd0`).

With device mapper (file sizes have to be multiple of 512):

```
sudo losetup /dev/loop0 file1
sudo losetup /dev/loop1 file2
s0=$(sudo blockdev --getsize /dev/loop0)
s1=$(sudo blockdev --getsize /dev/loop1)
printf '%s\n' "0 $s0 linear /dev/loop0 0" "$s0 $s1 linear /dev/loop1 0" |
  sudo dmsetup create mybundle
```

(the concatenation is `/dev/mapper/mybundle`).

Answer (score 17):

wrote a fuse driver today, if someone is interested in the fuse solution
(the device mapper as well as the nbd-solution above will create block devices not regular files - which will break, if you want to use the resulting output directly with video editing software or other tools which are not prepared to read from a block device directly)

https://github.com/schlaile/concatfs

Comment: Very educative and simple to use sourcecode! Thanks for making it and sharing!

Answer (score 3):

You basically answered it in the first sentence of the question: yes, it can be done. However, you'd have to write custom file system driver. If it is supposed to be a file system object, it has to be handled by the kernel on some level (that includes [FUSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace)). The driver would have to provide backend for the standard file system syscalls API (`stat()`, `open()` etc., including seeking). You can't do it entirely in user space (at least not with a monolithic kernel - but even with a microkernel you'd still need to provide a filesystem driver, albeit running as a regular userspace process).

Comment: It's fairly obvious that it can be done. What I'm curious about is whether there is any quick-hack way to achieve this using the standard un*x packages – preferably via bash w/o the need to write a dedicated kernel-space driver.

Comment: see Stephane's answer - I completely forgot the device mapper.