# Fastest way to concatenate files

Tags: bash, shell-script, files, cat

I've got 10k+ files totaling over 20GB that I need to concatenate into one file.

Is there a faster way than

```
cat input_file* >> out
```

?

The preferred way would be a bash command, Python is acceptable too if not considerably slower.

Comment: Updated my answer, `find` does not sort files the same as a shell glob.

Comment: Any and all (sane) solutions will have an equivalent speed here since the time will be 99% system I/O.

Comment: See also [A virtual file containing the concatenation of other files](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/94041/22565)

Comment: Considering writing the concatenated file in a different disk than the one(s) you're reading from.

Comment: It will be faster if `out` is located on another disk.

Comment: is there any order needed among the files?

Comment: In my case not, no

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Nope, cat is surely the best way to do this. Why use python when there is a program already written in C for this purpose? However, you might want to consider using `xargs` in case the command line length exceeds `ARG_MAX` and you need more than one `cat`. Using GNU tools, this is equivalent to what you already have:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name 'input_file*' -print0 |
  sort -z |
  xargs -0 cat -- >>out
```

Comment: Can you insure in this case that your files will be read in the order ?

Comment: Yes, because the output of `find` is piped through `sort`. Without this, the files would be listed in an arbitrary order (defined by the file system, which could be file creation order).

Comment: @scai I missread sorry, with sort it's pretty obvious

Comment: @Kiwy, the only case I can see is if the locale isn't properly set in the environment, then sort might behave differently from a `bash` glob. Otherwise I don't see any cases where `xargs` or `cat` would not behave as expected.

Comment: Do I read your last sentence correctly: the displayed code is _equivalent_ to the command OP gave ("what you already have"), and in particular _does not_ solve a potential `ARG_MAX` problem? I can see only one call of `cat` in the displayed code, so it does not address that problem at all.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen, `xargs` will call as may `cat` as is necessary to avoid an E2BIG error of execve(2).

Comment: @StephaneChazelas: Thank you for that information. I could not find this aspect of `xargs` behaviour documented anywhere on my (Ubuntu Linux) system.

Comment: @Marc, yes the `man` page for GNU `xargs` is pretty bad and misses a couple of major points of `xargs` operation.

Comment: cat might be the best common way, but its single threaded approach is not very fast.

Answer (score 25):

Allocating the space for the output file first may improve the overall speed as the system won't have to update the allocation for every write.

For instance, if on Linux:

```
size=$({ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name 'input_file*' -printf '%s+'; echo 0;} | bc)
fallocate -l "$size" out &&
  find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name 'input_file*' -print0 |
  sort -z | xargs -r0 cat 1<> out
```

Another benefit is that if there's not enough free space, the copy will not be attempted.

If on `btrfs`, you could `copy --reflink=always` the first file (which implies no data copy and would therefore be almost instantaneous), and append the rest. If there are 10000 files, that probably won't make much difference though unless the first file is very big.

There's an API to generalise that to ref-copy all the files (the `BTRFS_IOC_CLONE_RANGE` `ioctl`), but I could not find any utility exposing that API, so you'd have to do it in C (or `python` or other languages provided they can call arbitrary `ioctl`s).

If the source files are sparse or have large sequences of NUL characters, you could make a sparse output file (saving time and disk space) with (on GNU systems):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name 'input_file*' -print0 |
  sort -z | xargs -r0 cat | cp --sparse=always /dev/stdin out
```

Comment: love the pre-allocate, but should that be `>>out` instead of `>out` ?

Comment: but your example will not copy if `fallocate` fails to pre-allocate, e.g. because the filesystem does not support it (currently only `btrfs`, `ext4`, `ocfs2`, and `xfs` support `fallocate`); since there is little harm done if pre-allocation fails, i guess it's safer to use `fallocate -l "$size" out; find . ...`

Comment: @umläute, if fallocate fails because there's not enough space, then you'll waste time transferring everything. The solution assumes you're on a FS that supports fallocate. That's something you should be able to know beforehand.

Comment: @XTian, no, it should be neither `>` nor `>>`, but `1<>` as I said to write _into_ the file.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas - I still don't get `1<>`, could you please post a link to reference / explanation?

Comment: @grebneke, `<>` is the standard Bourne/POSIX read+write redirection operator. See your shell manual or [the POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07_07) for details. The default `fd` is `0` for the `<>` operator (`<>` is short for `0<>`, like `<` is short for `0<` and `>` short for `1>`), so you need the `1` to explicitly redirect stdout. Here, it's not so much that we need read+write (`O_RDWR`), but that we don't want `O_TRUNC` (as in `>`) which would deallocate what we've just allocated.

Comment: @grebneke, [`<>` was in the Bourne shell from the start](http://www.retro11.de/ouxr/u7ed/usr/src/cmd/sh/cmd.c.html#n:339) (1979) but initially [not documented](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/bourne/v7/).

Comment: @StephaneChazelas - Any references to example usage of read+write in bash? Since there is no `seek()` in bash (?), what are common real-world usages, except for skipping `O_TRUNC`? `man bash` is really terse on the subject, and it's hard to usefully google `bash <>`

Comment: @grebneke, http://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A22565+%22%3C%3E%22 will give you a few. ksh93 has seek operators BTW, and you can seek forward with `dd` or via reading.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas - thanks a lot, your help and knowledge is deeply appreciated!

Comment: I'm not convinced that there will be many cases where `fallocate` will negate the overhead of the extra `find`, even though it will be faster the second time round. `btrfs` certainly opens up some interesting possibilities though.