# Cannot merge files using cat

Tags: bash, cat

I tried to open a lot of files (10,000+) with `cat` and them merging them into one like this:

```
cat * > ~/Desktop/lol.xml
```

But it returned this error:

```
-bash: /bin/cat: Argument list too long
```

This means that its too long/large, what other way could I do this?

Comment: You could check the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18699165/1742825).

Comment: Also, some more useful read from [here as well](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118244/fastest-way-to-concatenate-files).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a limit for the number of arguments a command can take. A workaround is to use a `for loop` :

```
for file in *; do cat "$file"; done
```

The maximum can be displayed with :

```
$ getconf ARG_MAX
```

Comment: One `cat` instance per file, really?

Comment: For a one-shot interactive command, this is sufficient I think.

Answer (score 4):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f --exec cat {} + > ~/Desktop/lol.xml
```

This calls `cat` with the maximum possible number of arguments. For the remaining arguments new instances of `cat` are started.

Comment: Huh, that was quick, could you provide an explanation for this? It seems like it launches another `cat` process for every file.

Comment: `-maxdepth` is not POSIX, you can use `find ! -name . -prune -type f` instead.

Comment: Is this compatible with FreeBSD (OS X) tools? Just checking before.

Comment: @DisplayName I don't know. `-exec +` is part of the standard but has not always been. If that doesn't work then you can get a similar effect with `find ... -print | xargs -d '\n' cat >...` assuming there are no newlines in the file names.