# Can we create soft links that concatenate multiple files?

Tags: files, filesystems, symlink

Let's say that I have files `f1, ..., f9`. I want to create a  *single view* -- or a *soft link* -- say `f`, that displays a concatenated view over the 9 files.

For example, if I execute `wc -l f` the answer should be the sum of all individual `wc -l fi` for i in 1 to 9. If I edit any single file `fi` then the view `f` should automatically update, such as its modification time. So basically `f` is a soft link that tracks a sequence of files.

Is there any filesystem that supports something like this?

Comment: Would shell globbing work?  `wc -l f*`

Comment: For which commands do you want this 'soft link concatenation'?

Comment: Standard Unix doesn't have this but GNU/Hurd or Plan9 might, using some sort of special file that concatenates the set of files when read.  But I don't know enough about those systems to say something constructive.

Comment: @Kusalananda Linux can do that too with FUSE; but I'm not aware of any ready-made thing doing exactly that kind of thing (That kind of concatenation usually done at volume/device rather than file/inode level). Anyways, this has nothing to do with symlinks.

Comment: Real duplicate: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/94041/237982

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what you are planning to do a function might meet your requirements:

```
cf () { cat /path/to/f1 /path/to/f2 /path/to/f3; }
```

It wouldn't act as a file per say but you could use process substitution to fake it:

```
wc -l < <(cf)
```

Or in the example of `wc -l` it may be easier to just:

```
cf | wc -l
```