# How to insert a line in a file after certain bytes

Tags: linux, files, tail

Let's say I have a large file (several gigs) with `n` lines in it. I would like to add/insert a line after `k` bytes offset, from the beginning of the file, then what would be the fastest way to achieve that?

Comment: what did you try until now?

Comment: please let us know why you want to do it?

Comment: I was thinking of trying something like `head -c k file > temp.log; echo 'some data\n' >> temp.log; tail -c +(k+1) file > temp.log; mv temp.log file;` but not sure if its the best way to do this simple task..

Comment: Want to (ideally) achieve a way through which in-place insert into a file can be made possible..

Comment: **Lines** are, well, line-oriented objects, and bytes are raw, binary objects.  Do you need to add a line after X number of lines?

Comment: @yael it doesn't really matter why he wants to do it.

Comment: @RonJohn I would ideally like to add after a certain number bytes, but yeah, lines can work too. I have looked into those `sed` solutions, but the problem with them is that they are kind of expensive for larger files..

Comment: "*but the problem with them is that they are kind of expensive for larger files.*" and I was going to give you a sed example... :)

Comment: For Very Large Files, your standard Unix text tools might not be the best solution.  It certainly can't hurt to **try** `head -c k file > temp.log; echo 'some data\n' >> temp.log; tail -c +(k+1) file > temp.log; mv temp.log file` especially if it's a one-time operation.  It might have already completed by now.

Comment: One option could be to use `concatfs` which would provide a virtual file that presents the concatenation of the parts. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94041/a-virtual-file-containing-the-concatenation-of-other-files for more

Comment: The fastest way would be to write your own program, e.g. in C, to do that. It will still need to copy all the gigabytes after the line you insert. Because there's no real fast way to do it, the best advice is "don't use a sequential format of several gigabytes for inserts. Use a different format, e.g. a tree". Or split your large file into smaller files.

Comment: "Several gigs" does not sound too bad for a `sed` solution IMHO. I've done complicated `sed` editing on files that are several _hundred_ gigabytes.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a Python solution:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
"""split_bytes.py"""

import os
import sys

stdout = os.fdopen(sys.stdout.fileno(), 'wb')

path_to_file = sys.argv[1]
width_in_bytes = int(sys.argv[2])

with open(path_to_file, "rb") as f:
    byte = f.read(1)
    while byte:
        for i in range(width_in_bytes):
            stdout.write(byte)
            byte = f.read(1)
        stdout.write(b"\n")
```

You could execute it like this:

```bsh
python split_bytes.py path/to/file offset > new_file
```

As a test, I generated a 1GB file of random data:

```bsh
dd if=/dev/urandom of=data.bin bs=64M count=16 iflag=fullblock
```

Then ran the script on that file:

```bsh
python split_lines.py data.bin 10 > split-data.bin
```

Comment: This looks like a promising approach..let me try some tests.

Answer (score 0):

a **bash** only solution :

use split command :

```
split --lines=2 --suffix-length=6 /etc/passwd /tmp/split.passwd.part
```

reassemble the file into one new

```
(
  for F in /tmp/split.passwd.part* ; 
  do 
    cat $F ; 
    echo ; 
  done
) > /tmp/passwd_emptyline_evrey_2
```