# Join files together without using space in filesystem

Tags: files, deduplication

I want to join (concatenate) two files in Linux without using space in the filesystem. Can I do this?

```
A + B = AB
```

The file `AB` use sectors or fragments of `A` and `B` from the filesystem. Is it possible to do this?

Could I use `gparted` to recognize `AB` as a new file without copying two files (which is a slow process)?

Comment: Gparted doesn't deal with files at all... So it's not really clear what you need. Please elaborate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A virtual file containing the concatenation of other files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/94041)

Answer (score 1):

I'm supposing you have a very large disk image split into large files `f1`, `f2` and `f3` and want to modify the partitions in that disk image. Then assuming the size of all files are multiple of 512, you could do (as root)

```
offset=0
for f in f1 f2 f3; do
   loop=$(losetup -f --show -- "$f")
   size=$(blockdev --getsz "$loop")
   printf '%s\n' "$offset $size linear $loop 0"
   offset=$(( offset + size ))
done | dmsetup create myimg
```

Then you can do a `gparted /dev/mapper/myimg`, and even format and mount the partitions it creates afterwards.

To tear down that device:

- make sure all filesystems and other resources on it are unmounted / freed
- `dmsetup remove myimg`
- run `losetup -d` on each loop device.

Answer (score 0):

[Process substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_substitution) can be used to concatenate two or more files so that they appear to be one file for a process e.g. `some_program <(cat A B)`.

However, that wouldn't make any sense to use with `gparted` or any other program that's meant to modify the input file - it's not a real file, it's a fifo, an anonymous pipe, and it's ephemeral.  The "file" created by `<()` is also read-only and non-seekable (i.e. it can only be read sequentially).

Process substitution also includes `>()` for redirecting stdout to a process, but that still wouldn't be of any use with `gparted`, which expects to be working with a real block device or disk image file.